# Killed `rm` and `cp` on nfs share

Tags: nfs, rm, cp, debugging, troubleshooting

I am just testing an `rsnapshot` installation on my laptop which should backup to a NAS mounted via `nfs` on my laptop.

On one test `rsnapshot` died with a `cp -al` problem (i.e. a problem with hard links) when moving `daily.0` to `daily.1`, I think the problem was when it tried to copy the `../etc/alternatives/` part...

During debugging I tried to remove the directory `daily.0` on the `nfs` manually on command line, however `rm` exited with the message `killed`. A similar problem occured with `cp` a few days ago though I cannot reproduce it (`cp` between two `nfs` subdirectories exited also with the message `killed`).

So is there any way to get more informative error messages from `rm` and `cp` to find out what's the actual problem is?

**Edit**
After reading kyle-jones anwer I watched my RAM usage during several operations and confirmed that when I do something on my `nfs` mount on large directories, my memory fills up very fast up to 4GB (that's my physical memory on my laptop) and then the process is killed.

This happend for: `cp`, `rm`, `du` and even for `ls`.

As mount options for my `nfs` mount I used:

`-o rw,hard,intr,tcp,actimeo=3` (and specified `nfs` via `-t nfs`).

Answer (score 2):

The "Killed" message isn't coming from `rm` or `cp`, rather it's coming from the shell telling you that the process was forcibly terminated with signal 9.  The usual reason this happens is that the operating system is running low on memory and swap space and has no choice but to randomly kill processes to free up RAM.

Comment: Thanks, I just confirmed it seeing my RAM usage increased from 0,8 GB to 4 GB in a few seconds while trying to use `rm` on my `nfs` mount. When it reached the 4 GB it was instantly killed.